# Simple has_many not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to do a very simple has many.

I want a profile to be associated with many reviews. Right now if I try to do a save on a review the console outputs BEGIN and then immediately ROLLBACK saying Euserprofile must exist.

```
class EUserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :EUserRevs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :EUserProfiles,
                          class_name: "EUserProfile",
                          join_table: :e_user_friends,
                          foreign_key: :E_USER_FRIEND_TO,
                          association_foreign_key: :E_USER_FRIEND_FROM

  has_and_belongs_to_many :EUserProfiles,
                          class_name: "EUserProfile",
                          join_table: :e_user_follows,
                          foreign_key: :E_USER_FOLR,
                          association_foreign_key: :E_USER_FOLG
end


class CreateEUserRevs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :e_user_revs, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string "E_USER_REV"
      t.string "E_USER_REVING", :null => false
      t.integer "E_USER_SCORE", :null => false
      t.string "E_USER_COMMENT", :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end

  end

  def down

    drop_table :e_user_revs
  end
end

class CreateEUserProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :e_user_profiles do |t|
      t.string "E_USER_PROFILE_USERNAME", :null => false
      t.string "E_USER_PROFILE_FIRST_NAME", :null => false
      t.string "E_USER_PROFILE_LOC"
      t.string "E_USER_PROFILE_BIO"
      t.string "E_USER_PROFILE_INSTR", :null => false
      t.string "E_USER_PROFILE_GENR", :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :e_user_profiles
  end
end

class EUserRev < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :EUserProfile
end
```

Comment: Whats with the atrocious column naming scheme?

Comment: Do you just have no clue what you are doing or are you trying to work with a legacy database?

Comment: What does the `EUserProfle` class look like?  Also, you can't have two `has_and_belongs_to_many :EUserProfiles`  ... how would you distinguish them in use?  It should be `has_and_belongs_to_many :friends...` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :followers...` so you can reference `@my_profile.friends` and `@my_profile.followers` ... as it is you'd be referencing `@my_profile.EUserProfiles` and wouldn't know which you're getting back.  Also, for heaven's sake, get rid of the Capital Letters.  Use them for constants only, including class names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a simple one-to-many relation.

you need to add the following line to the CreateEUserRevs migration file:

```
t.belongs_to : eu_user_profile, index: true
```

that will add e_user_profile_id field for EUserRevs schema.
After doing that, you can use has_many (in EUserProfile model) and belongs_to (in EUserRev model).

Remember, these helpers, given by ActiveRecord, will work only if the DB schema will fit.

You can read more about associations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Did you dropped the db and re-run the migrations? There might be a type in the naming conventions as well

Comment: I did, so Im still not sure what's going on.

Comment: Can you type the command you try to run when you receive the error?

Comment: rev = EUserRev.new(:E_USER_REVING => '2', :E_USER_SCORE => 5, :E_USER_COMMENT => 'Very nice!') and then rev.save

Comment: first I just notice you wrote up above "has and belongs to many", these lines should be removed. I can also see that your models are inheriting from ApplicationRecord and not from ActiveRecord::Base. Please fix these two issues. Then, when you create a new EUserRev, add another parameter-  e_user_profile_id , values with the right user profile id.

Comment: Rails 5 sets up ApplicationRecord as the superclass for your models when you use the generator. Exactly like ApplicationController is for controllers.